# Find on which $z=x+iy\in\mathbb{C}$ the function $f(z)=(\overline{z}+1)^3 - 3\overline{z}$ is differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

I'm solving past exam questions in preparation for an Applied Mathematics course. I came to the following exercise, which poses some difficulty. *If it's any indication of difficulty, the exercise is only Part 3-Β of the sheet, graded for 10%*

> Find on which $z=x+iy\in\mathbb{C}$ the function $f(z)=(\overline{z}+1)^3 - 3\overline{z}$ is differentiable

---

My first thought is that I have to prove $f$ to be constant.
Let $z=x+iy$, $\overline{z}=x-iy$.

So

\begin{align}f(z) &= (x-iy)^3 - 3(x-iy) \\&= (x-iy)(x^2 -i2xy +i^2y^2) - 3(x-iy)\\&= x^3 -i3x^y - 3xy^2 -iy^3 -3x + 3iy\end{align}

First off, this whole thing looks like a mess.

Am I supposed to continue with calculating $u(x,y)$, $v(x,y)$, then the partial derrivatives $u_x$,$u_y$,$v_x$,$v_y$ to check if 
\begin{align}
u_x &= v_y \\
u_y &= -v_x \\
\end{align}

so the C-R are valid for every $x, y$?

Is this adequate to then say that the whole of $f(z)$ is differentiable for any complex $z$?

I'm sorry for this whole question but this exercise has me stumped.

Comment: Fact: if $f(z)$ is entire then $f(\overline{z})$ is not analytic except at most one point.  You have $f(z)$ polynomial which is entire so $f(\overline{z})$ is not analytic except at $z=0$.

Comment: Things often look messy when you quit too early. Don't stop, keep going, calculate $u$ and $v$, and use the CR equations, just as you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing $f$ as a function $(x,y)\mapsto f(x+iy)$ write it as
$$q(z,\bar z):=(\bar z+1)^3-3\bar z=\bar z^3+3\bar z^2+1\ .$$
The given $f$ is complex differentiable at the points $z$ where
$${\partial q\over\partial\bar z}=3\bar z^2+6\bar z=0\ ,$$
i.e., at the points $z=0$ and $z=-2$.

(Treating the problem this way differs from $u_x=v_y$, $u_y=-v_x$ and solving for $(x,y)$ by mere linear algebra. There is no complex magic behind this.)